# Hibernate mapping for SQL Server 'XML' datatype

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, mapping

I want to map a xml data type from sql server to hibernate with Java. I know about user types, but I don't know how.

Comment: what do you want? `I want to map a xml data type from sql server to hibernate with Java`. what is this?

Comment: In a hbm I want to put a field from sql server which is type xml and hibernate doesn't have this type. Could you help me to create a user type for xml data type from sql server with java?. I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, take your time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), it might help you improve your questions, and get better answers. You might be interested in this possibly duplicate question: [JPA support for XML datatype columns](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3637363/851811). Also, [Stack Overflow is not a research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553)

Comment: Xavier, I have seen this what you say, but it doesn't work for me, because of, I need SQL server, not ORACLE. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate maps the XML data type in SQL server automatically. Just use a string in your Java class.

```
@Column(name = "my_xml_column")
private String myXML;
```