# Hibernate: Persist XML values without Java Classes

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there any hibernate utility which allows to persist xml values in database without marshaling it into java classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA support for XML datatype columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637363/jpa-support-for-xml-datatype-columns)

Answer (score 1):

No. While I can imagine this is possible with Hibernate, it's the wrong tool for the task. Hibernate was created specifically to map Entities to DB rows.

You will either have to implement a DOM-like structure which defines the entities which Hibernate should use or write the importer using plain JDBC or maybe create some simple entities which you fill from XML and then persist with Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong persistence library, maybe try using iBatis.