# XML and JPA(eclipse-link)

Tags: java, xml, jpa

Is there a way to map an xml datatype to database using jpa (eclipse-link) and query them without the use of native x query?

Comment: Your question is vague. Yes, you can map entities using only XML. Yes you can query for entities without using native SQL. Using native SQL is not very common with JPA. Do you have anything special in mind?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637363/jpa-support-for-xml-datatype-columns

Comment: hey, hey @kostja i believe you misunderstand  the question i am not asking if i can map entity using xml. i am asking if an entity can be stored as xml field (datatype) in the database using jpa then how to query such entiyt.

Comment: :) ah, now I get it. No, there is no XML-specific mapping  in JPA up to and including 2.1. If your XML can be longer than a sensible varchar setting, which is mostly the case, you can use Lob.

Comment: my problem not with size , my problem is with search i won't to evade use of native query  in order to search this fields. thanks @kostja.